# Induction principle problem

Tags: calculus, induction

Given

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \right\rfloor \!\ = \begin{cases} \dfrac{n^2}{4}, & \mbox{if } n\mbox{ is even} \\[1ex] \dfrac{n^2-1}{4}, & \mbox{if } n\mbox{ is odd} \end{cases}$$

for every natural number $n$.

If I put $n=0$ I get $0=0$ but if I put $n=1$ I get $\dfrac{1}{2}=0$. Why?

Comment: If $n=1$, you also have $0=0$.

Comment: As was mentioned on your other post, $\big\lfloor\dfrac{1}{2}\big\rfloor=0$, so you get the expected result.

Comment: If you want to allow $n=0$, it would make sense to start the sum at $i=0$ rather than $i=1$.

Answer (score 0):

When $n = 1$, the left-hand-side becomes $\left\lfloor \dfrac12 \right\rfloor = 0$, which is consistent with the right-hand-side.  The error occurs because of the omission of the floor sign.

Comment: How can I prove that $\frac{n^2}{4}=\frac{(n+2)^2}{4}$?

Comment: @user557276 No, you can't.  Consider the case when $n=0$.

Comment: The exercise tells me to prove that $P(n)→P(n+2)$

Comment: @user557276 What is $P(n)$?

Comment: It's the original expression. I have to prove that $P(n)→P(n+2)$ first when $n$ is even and then when $n$ is odd

Comment: You mean the given equation in the question body?  You don't even need induction to prove this.

Comment: I'm just doing what the exercise asks me to do. Can you help me?

Comment: Drawing a [graph like this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/File:LQR.png) can help you to gain a geometric insight to the problem.  In this way, you'll understand how the identity arises *without* induction.  Then, you can construct the arguments needed for the exercise to practise your skill in writing an inductive proof.To start with,1. adapt the linked graph to this problem (i.e. changing the vertices of the rectangle so that they fit into this problem.) 2.Work on an easier case ($n$ even).  When can you observe? 3.Assume the previous result, extend this to another case (by a counting argument).

Comment: @user557276, you need to be clear about what "$P(n)$" and "$P(n+2)$" mean.  Proving $P(n)\implies P(n+2)$ is not at all the same as proving ${n^2\over4}={(n+2)^2\over4}$. For one thing, the latter is not true for all $n$, only for $n=-1$.